# I am getting error wihile using filter in pig ,when i dump result it gives error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

code used in pig is :

```
studentsR = LOAD 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/students/students' using PigStorage() as (name:chararray,rollno:int);
resultR = LOAD 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/students/results' using PigStorage() as (rollno:int,result:chararray);
joniR = JOIN studentsR BY rollno,resultR BY rollno;
filterR = FOREACH joniR GENERATE (studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result) ;
filterRPass = FILTER filterR BY resultR.result == 'pass';
dump filterRPass;
```

error coming as below :

```
ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (1,fail), 2nd :(2,fail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dump and describe for your every result set to see the output of each alias used.

Refer : [scalar-has-more-than-one-row-in-the-output](https://dev.pig.apache.narkive.com/NJFwnVbw/jira-created-pig-4525-clarify-scalar-has-more-than-one-row-in-the-output)

```
studentsR = LOAD '/home/user/students' using PigStorage(' ') as (name:chararray,rollno:int);
dump studentsR;
resultR = LOAD '/home/user/results' using PigStorage(' ') as (rollno:int,result:chararray);
dump resultR;
joniR = JOIN studentsR BY rollno,resultR BY rollno;
dump joniR;
filterR = FOREACH joniR GENERATE studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result;
dump filterR;
filterRPass = FILTER filterR BY resultR::result == 'pass';
dump filterRPass;
```

**Modifications:**

I used space in the input files as delimiter so used PigStorage(' ')

In filterR i removed the opening and closing round braces () around  studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result since output of dump was having additional round braces.

```
grunt> filterR = FOREACH joniR GENERATE (studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result);
grunt> describe  filterR;
filterR: {org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_studentsR::name_100: (studentsR::name: chararray,studentsR::rollno: int,resultR::result: chararray)}
grunt> filterR = FOREACH joniR GENERATE studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result;
grunt> describe  filterR;
filterR: {studentsR::name: chararray,studentsR::rollno: int,resultR::result: chararray}
```

Used resultR::result instead of resultR.result in fifilterRPass

I have used a local set of files and executed pig in local mode for testing.

```
cat students
a 1
b 2
c 3

cat results
3 pass
2 fail
5 pass
```

**Dump results:**

```
dump studentsR
(a,1)
(b,2)
(c,3)

dump resultR
(3,pass)
(2,fail)
(5,pass)

dump joniR
(b,2,2,fail)
(c,3,3,pass)

dump filterR --filterR = FOREACH joniR GENERATE (studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result);
((b,2,fail))
((c,3,pass))

dump filterR --filterR = FOREACH joniR GENERATE studentsR::name,studentsR::rollno,resultR::result;
(b,2,fail)
(c,3,pass)

dump filterRPass; --filterRPass = FILTER filterR BY resultR::result == 'pass';  --or-- filterRPass = FILTER filterR BY $2 == 'pass';
(c,3,pass)
```

Comment: thanks for answering ... i worked like charm...... I am new to hadoop and pig can u explain me when to use resultR::result , resultR:result , resultR.result .......

Comment: @AnshulBisht As far as i understood while loading/assigning we use single colon and while retrieving/calling data we use double colon.